# Vue unnecessarily re-renders entire all children components at every small change

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, virtual-dom, vue-class-components

I have an issue within a complex project: Somehow, Vue re-renders all children at every change

We use vue 2.5.17 with typescrip, class components and decorators.

I created a new, clean component that is not at all tied to other logic within our project:

```js
import { Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import Vue, { CreateElement } from 'vue'

@Component
class InnerElement extends Vue {

  @Prop({ required: true })
  value: number

  render (h: CreateElement) {
    console.log('render InnerElement: ' + this.value)
    return <div key={this.value}>Value: {this.value}</div>
  }
}

@Component
export class Outside extends Vue {

  list: number[]
  parentCounter: number

  constructor () {
    super()
    this.list = []
    this.parentCounter = 0
  }

  addElement () {
    this.list.push(this.list.length)
  }

  render (h: CreateElement) {
    console.log('render parent')
    return <div>
      <div>Outside component counter: {this.parentCounter}</div>
      <button onClick={() => {
        console.log('Increase counter')
        this.parentCounter++
      }}>Increase counter</button>
      <div>{this.list.map(item => <InnerElement value={item} />)}</div>
      <button onClick={this.addElement}>Add element</button>
    </div>
  }
}
```

Normally, when I would click on 'Increase counter', none of the `InnerElement` children should be re-rendered. When I add a new item into the `list` array, only the newly added element should be renderd.

I have tested this in a new, clean project and it works as expected.
In the project where we have the problem, this is the behaviour: I add a new element, all the existing ones are re-rendered. I increase the counter, all the elements are re-rendered:


This is how it looks if I do the following flow: add 4 elements and in the end, increase the counter:
[image]


This is the normal behavior, in a newly created project, for the exact same flow:
[image]


The dummy project uses vue 2.6.11 and I didn't bothered with adding webpack-dev-server, vuex and maybe some other libraries because I don't think these should impact the way things are rendered.

I am totally out of ideas, I don't have the smallest clew of where to look, couldn't find anything on the internet so far.

Thank you!

Comment: I have zero experience wit JSX so I could be wrong but why do you have a `key` on the `<div>` inside `InnerElement` ? The `key` should be placed on the `InnerElement` when it is rendered in `Outside` component...

Comment: `InnerElement` returns the contend of `render` method, so, a `<div>`  that already has the `key` set. `InnerElement` it's just a wrapper, the html resulted will be the same as if I would write it by hand, html element by html element. Beside this, in one case it works and in the other case it does not. @MichalLevý